# Firebase Realtime Database orderBy() query does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database that looks like this

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

My browser extension is for creating stories. And each story (under 'userStories') is associated with a particular user (authUID). authID is the id the user is logged in with using Firebase Authentication. Each story receives a key generated by push() when writing to 'stories'.

I am trying to retrieve data using Javascript and sort it in reverse order. I want to display the last story created first.

My JavaScript code (does not work by the way) looks like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/userStories/'+authUID).orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{
  sendResponse({type: "result", status: "success", data: snapshot.val(), request: request})
})
```

My question is what's wrong with my query statement?

Nothing is happening in terms of sorting. Whether I try `orderByValue()`, `orderByKey()` or `orderByChild()` makes no difference.

Why are the results not being sorted.

Edit:

If my modify my code to the following...

```
      firebase.database().ref('/userStories/'+authUID).orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
      {
        let results = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          console.log(child.key,child.val)
          results.push({ key: child.key, value: child.val() });
          console.log(results)
         })
        sendResponse({type: "result", status: "success", data: results, request: request})
      })
```

This is the output to the console...

[image: Console.log Output]

As you can see the sorting order is still ascending (which is not what I want).

I want the results in descending order.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Edit:

I got some results (not exactly what I was looking for) by adding the line `results.reverse()` to reverse the array. There's a sort of the last key but the rest are all mixed up.

```
      {
        let results = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          console.log(child.key,child.val)
          results.push({ key: child.key, value: child.val() });
          results.reverse()
          console.log(results)
         })
        sendResponse({type: "result", status: "success", data: results, request: request})
      })
```

The results on the console are:

[image: Sorted results in Descending order]

Edit:

Sorry to make so many edits but this is the last one. I found a solution by using a spread operator [...] to make copy of the array results and then reverse it. I added the line `res = [...results].reverse()` and I this time the results are sorted in descending order.

```
firebase.database().ref('/userStories/'+authUID).orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
      {
        let results = [];
        let res = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          console.log(child.key,child.val)
          results.push({ key: child.key, value: child.val() });
          res = [...results].reverse()
          console.log(res)
         })

        sendResponse({type: "result", status: "success", data: res, request: request})
      })
```

Here are the results:
[image: Sorted Results]

Answer (score 4):

Keys in JSON are unordered. So while `snapshot` has the information about the order of the results, that information is lost as soon as you call `snapshot.val()`.

If you want to maintain the information about order, you'll want to use `snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results.

For example, you could convert the results into an array of keys and values:

```
firebase.database().ref('/userStories/'+authUID).orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{
  let results = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    results.push({ key: child.key, value: child.val() });
  });
  sendResponse({type: "result", status: "success", data: results, request: request})
})
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I modified my post to include what happened after running your modifications. Unfortunately, it's not helping. The order is still in ascending order.

Comment: Hi. I added results.reverse() after the results.push() statement to reverse the order of the results.

Comment: Oh yeah, the results will always be in ascending order. If that was the only problem (instead of them being in a *random* order), see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+query+descending

Comment: that firebase realtime database query capabilities are just ridiculous. It kinda makes sense though that `val()` doesn't work as it gives you JSON where order isn't really a thing, but still... Anyway, thanks for the answer, `forEach` and constructing my own collection helped.